# How to disable the extra bold lines under error and warning underlines?

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

I installed this new theme called [Panda Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tinkertrain.theme-panda). Everything looks good except for the two extra bold lines under the wavy error and warning underline. This happens to all languages.

Does anyone know where to change this back to the default, but still keep the theme?

example image of error underline, and the default that I want it to be
[image: example image]

Comment: look in the theme colors and find the name for these colors, name could contain `warning` or `error` and customize the color for this theme, or find the color code of the lines and search the pandas extension for that color to get the theme name

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes these two lines `editorError.border` and `editorWarning.border` was in charge of the extra lines. Putting these into setting.json helped. Thanks @rioV8 for the suggestion.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorError.border": "#00000000",
    "editorWarning.border": "#00000000",
}
```